# How to access Firebase Hosting project target ID from inside function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a multi-site Firebase Hosting setup that is working very well serving both static content and dynamic meta tags. I'm currently checking the referrer to read the correct index file however it's not reliable and doesn't work with localhost.

**Can I access the `target` property from my `firebase.json` from inside the function?**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');

exports.injectMeta = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const URL = url.parse(req.url);

    // HOW CAN I GE THE CURRENT TARGET ID FROM FIREBASE.JSON?

    let prefix = 'tam';
    if (URL.host === 'example1.com') { // this is not reliable and doesn't work with localhost
        prefix = 'foo';
    } else if (URL.host === 'example2.com') {
        prefix = 'bar';
    } else if (URL.host === 'example3.com') {
        prefix = 'woo';
    }

    const template = fs.readFileSync(`./build/${prefix}/index.html`, 'utf8');

    let meta = '';
    if (URL.pathname.indexOf('/zoo/') === 0 ||
        URL.pathname.indexOf('/zaz/') === 0) {
        meta += `<meta property="og:url" content="https://api.example.com/sharer${URL.pathname}" />`;
    }

    meta += `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXX" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="other dynamic stuff" />`;

    res.status(200).send(template.replace("<head>", "<head>" + meta));
});
```

My firebase.json looks like

```
{
    "functions": {
        "predeploy": [
            "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
            "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
        ]
    },
    "hosting": [
        {
            "target": "tam",
            "public": "functions/build/tam",
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "/group/**",
                    "function": "injectMeta"
                },
                {
                    "source": "/marketplace/**",
                    "function": "injectMeta"
                },
                {
                    "source": "/faqs/**",
                    "function": "injectMeta"
                },
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html"
                }
            ],
            "headers": [
                {
                    "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                            "value": "*"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "max-age=7200"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "source": "404.html",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "max-age=300"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "ignore": [
                "**/.*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "target": "ftb",
            "public": "functions/build/ftb",
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "/group/**",
                    "function": "injectMeta"
                },
                {
                    "source": "/marketplace/**",
                    "function": "injectMeta"
                },
                {
                    "source": "/faqs/**",
                    "function": "injectMeta"
                },
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html"
                }
            ],
            "headers": [
                {
                    "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                            "value": "*"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "max-age=7200"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "source": "404.html",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "max-age=300"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "ignore": [
                "**/.*"
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding it as an [environment variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) at the time you deploy the function.  These are used to configure function deployments so you don't have to hard code anything.  You should also check to see if the [automatically populated values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) are something you might want to use.

Comment: turns out none of these will give me the hosting target name. process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT is the top level project ID and FIREBASE_CONFIG does not include the hosting targets either.

Comment: OK, so use your own environment variables as I suggested.

Comment: Environment Variables are set on a project level. So cannot identify a Hosting Target.

Comment: You can put whatever you want in env vars for your deployment, and you can deploy different variables for each project.

Comment: Yes, but Hosting Targets are different domains / apps within a single project. My function needs to identify which target (domain) is running. i'm looking for something better than `url.parse(req.url).host`

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a whole new question now.  The one embedded in your code asks: "HOW CAN I GE THE CURRENT TARGET PROJECT ID FROM FIREBASE.JSON".  If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but the question does and has always asked about the `target`. I added the firebase.json and removed "project id" to clarify your confusion.

Comment: also i just added a `console.log(url.parse(req.url))` and hostname is `null` no matter the domain